# Match a line until a # ,but without the #, when parsing a file with a regex

Tags: bash, debian, regex

I want to parse my `sources.list` to extract the list of repositories. I have:

```
## Some comment
deb http://some.vendor.com/ubuntu precise stable
deb-src http://some.vendor.com/ubuntu precise stable
deb http://some.othervendor.com/ubuntu precise experimental # my current favorite
```

I want:

```
http://some.vendor.com/ubuntu precise stable
http://some.othervendor.com/ubuntu precise experimental
```

So I need: only lines with “deb” at the beginning and until the end of the line or a `#` character, but excluding it. So far I have:

```
grep -o "^deb .*"
```

But how do I match `#` or end of line without matching the `#`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(?<=^deb\s).*?(?=#|$)' inputFiles
```

Based on @[kopischke's suggestion](https://superuser.com/users/101110/kopischke),

```
grep -Po '(?<=^deb\s)[^#]*' inputFiles
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
sed -nr '/^deb\s/s;^deb\s([^#]*)#?.*$;\1;p' inputFiles
```

---

Using`awk`(This solution is based on number of fixed fields):

```
awk '/^deb /{print $2,$3,$4}' inputFiles
```

---

Comment: +1 for the `grep` Perl regex (never noticed that one, guess “Perl” made me skip over it :)). However, you don’t need the lookahead to exclude the hash – a negated character class, i.e. `[^#]*`, will do just fine (line end doesn’t need to be expressly matched – grep matches line by line anyway).

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `sed` or `awk` for such a simple match; just have your regex grab any character but a hash by using a negated character class:

```
grep -o "^deb [^#]*"
```

If you need to filter out the leading “deb ”, a simple loop will do:

```
while read line; do
    echo "${line#deb }"
done <(grep -o "^deb [^#]*")
```

**Edit:** a cleaner, one line solution is to use a Perl regex with `grep -P`, which allows for lookbehind assertions (see [Prince John Wesley’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/434955/101110)).

Comment: I don't think the OP want the initial `"deb "`.

Comment: @cYrus: you could be right – the posted regex suggests otherwise, but the expected result is admittedly missing the leading “deb ”. Amended my answer to account for both cases.